# How to copy file contents from remote server to local machine location?

Tags: linux

### Copy the File contents

1.How can i copy the file contents from remote server location(i.e ssh ru@9.122.145.169) to (/home/remo/remo/php=>local location ).

I tried the following ways:

```
[remo@oc perl]$ ssh ru@9.122.145.169
Password: 
Last login: Mon Nov 20 08:33:41 2017 from oc.im.com
Installation image server SLES10 / OpenDeployServer
ru@e7:~> vi index.php
```

I want to copy the contents from(index.php) file tomy local location ( home/remo/remo/perl)

command which i had tried which as follows but it failed in my case:

```
cp index.php /home/remo/remo/php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use scp to to this :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy

in your case :

```
scp ru@9.122.145.169:/<pathtofile>/index.php /home/remo/remo/php
```

you will be prompted to enter your password in the same way of ssh does

Comment: I tried with the above command but it takes time to connect shows the message as connection timed out @Pierre Mallet

Comment: you have a connection timeout using scp and not when connecting throught ssh ? Could you put the entires commands and results for both ssh and scp ?